# How to create circular and triangular buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, xcode7

Below I have attached code I am currently using to create a blue button in Swift 2, Xcode 7

I wanted to know if there was a way to create the button as a triangle, and a circle.

```
    let btn = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton        
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    btn.setTitle("CALL TPT AGENT", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "clickMe:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btn)
```

Any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: do you know about bezierpath? for circle you can use btn.layer.cornerRadius give some value(if ur frame is a square then value is half of the hight or width)

Comment: Thanks, I worked. However, after adding this - 'btn.layer.cornerRadius = 50' and clicking on this, the app crashes. Do you know whats going on? @Ramkumarchintala

Comment: can u add the crash log here

Comment: My crash log has always been broken, so it just says "Failed to Attach"... Do you see anything in the code that could be causing this? @Ramkumarchintala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw a triangle, here is the code

```
let trianglePath = UIBezierPath()
let triangleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
//change the CGPoint values to get the triangle of the shape you want
trianglePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50))
trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100))
trianglePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

triangleLayer.path = trianglePath.cgPath
triangleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

btn.layer.addSublayer(triangleLayer)
```

Comment: Also, no matter how hard i try, I can't seem to get the triangle to be an equilateral and right side up... any help? :)

Comment: @Nosh
Let the distance between your points be x, you need your "halfway line" to have a length of √3 / 2 * x
This means your points should have those coordinates:
(0, 0)

Comment: Here are the coordinates

(0, 0) (50, 86.6) (100, 0) and back to (0, 0)
To have the triangle point the other way around:
(0, 86.6) (100, 86.6) (50, 86.6) and back to (0, 86.6)
Tell me if those orientations suit you

Answer (score 4):

Why not create triangle and circle images (with image file or dynamically) then set the button image accordingly :

```
enum Shape {
    case Triangle, Circle
}

class ShapeButton : UIButton
{
    var shapeColor:UIColor!
    var buttonShape:Shape!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let button1  = UIButton(type:  .custom)
    button1.frame = CGRect(x:100, y:50, width:50, height:50)
    if let image = UIImage(named:"circle.png") {
        button1.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
    self.view.addSubview(button1)

    let button2  = ShapeButton(type:  .custom)
    button2.shapeColor = UIColor.red
    button2.buttonShape = Shape.Triangle
    button2.frame = CGRect(x:50, y:50, width:50, height:50)
    if let image = drawCustomImage(size:button2.frame.size,imageShape: button2.buttonShape,color:button2.shapeColor) {
        button2.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
    self.view.addSubview(button2)

    let button3  = ShapeButton(type:  .custom)
    button3.buttonShape = Shape.Circle
    button3.shapeColor = UIColor.green
    button3.frame = CGRect(x:150, y:50, width:50, height:50)
    if let image = drawCustomImage(size:button3.frame.size,imageShape: button3.buttonShape,color:button3.shapeColor) {
        button3.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
    self.view.addSubview(button3)

}

func drawCustomImage(size: CGSize,imageShape:Shape,color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    // Setup our context
    let bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
    let opaque = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 0
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }

    // Setup complete, do drawing here
    context.setStrokeColor(color.cgColor) //UIColor.red.cgColor
    context.setLineWidth(1)

    // Would draw a border around the rectangle
    // context.stroke(bounds)

    context.beginPath()
    if imageShape == Shape.Triangle {
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX/2, y: bounds.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY))
    } else {
        context.addEllipse(in: bounds)
    }
    context.closePath()

    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.fillPath()

    // Drawing complete, retrieve the finished image and cleanup
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be the best option, but I need to be able to identify and change the colour of the shapes, and It would be easier to have all the colours inside a dictionary in the code.

Comment: Edited my answer - added ShapeButton inheriting from UIButton, added shape and colour properties. Updated drawCustomImage to draw triangle or circle.

Answer (score 0):

For circular Buttons, in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = 90
```

For triangular Buttons, this might be helpful: [Swiftiotutorials - Nice Triangle View Border](http://swiftiostutorials.com/tutorial-draw-nice-triangle-view-border-cashapelayer/)

Comment: To add on to this answer ensure that your button constraints are set to 1:1, or else this may not give you a circle.

Comment: @Jerland2 yes, sorry, I forgot mentioning that!

Comment: Thanks! Is the button constraints automatically set to 1:1?

Comment: @Nosh by 1:1 constraints we meant that the height and width of the button are nearly equal

Comment: Dude! We don’t speak Chinese!  (Looks like the like has changed)

Answer (score 0):

I always make rounded buttons by setting `btn.layer.cornerRadius = btn.frame.height / 2` That way the button ends are alway rounded no matter how tall the button is. If you want a circle set the width and the height to the same thing.